# issue with calculating precision and recall for SVM model in R

Tags: r

I use census-data to build logistic regression model and SVM model, first, I convert <=50K to 0, >50K to 1 to make the data binomial. I try to calculate precision and recall for both models and compare which model perform better? But table(test$salary,pred1 >0.5)  for SVM model in r says < table of extent 2 x 0 >
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(pred1, 0.5) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
but similar code is working for logistic regression model.  I am new to R software, I hope that I can get help from here.Thanks a lot. Any help is welcome. 
 I hope the question is clear enough.

```
#setwd("C:/Users/)
Censusdata <- read.csv(file="census-data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
library("dplyr", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")
df <- Censusdata[,]

# convert <=50K to 0, >50K to 1
df$salary <- as.numeric(factor(df$salary))-1
head(df,10)
library(lattice)
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)
data <- Censusdata
indexes <- sample(1:nrow(data),size=0.7*nrow(data))
test <- data[indexes,]
train <- data[-indexes,]

#logistic regression model fit
model <- glm(salary ~ education.num + hours.per.week,family = binomial,data = test)
pred <- predict(model,data=train)
summary(model)

# calculate precision and recall 
table(test$salary,pre >0.5)

# for SVM model 
model1 <- svm(salary ~ education.num + hours.per.week,family = binomial, data=test)
pred1 <- predict(model1,data=train)
table(test$salary,pred1 >0.5)
```

Comment: Where do you calculate your predicted values? Hint: `predict` is the _function_ you use, not the predictions themselves.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hong Ooi, I totally forgot the predict part. I was revisiting my code. I can get really confused since I am very new to R.

Comment: @Hong Ooi, Do you know why table(test$salary,pred1 >0.5) for svm model does't work? Thanks in advance.